# Rails nested_form Invalid association. Make sure that accepts_nested_attributes_for is used for assoctiation

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, associations, nested-form-for

I am using rails 4.0.4 with nested_form 0.3.2 to build an app that allows users to organize movies in lists.

I have these main models, a List model (I've excluded things such as validations):

```
class List < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :list_movie_pairs
  has_many :movies, :through => :list_movie_pairs

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :list_movie_pairs, :allow_destroy => true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :movies, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

A Movie model:

```
class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :list_movie_pairs
  has_many :lists, :through => :list_movie_pairs
  has_many :reviews
end
```

A ListMoviePair model for the many-to-many relationship:

```
class ListMoviePair < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :list
  belongs_to :movie

  validates_presence_of :list_id, :movie_id
  validates_uniqueness_of :movie_id, scope: :list_id
end
```

I am trying to build an interface for the user to add movies to a created list. These routes serve my purpose:

```
get "/users/:username/lists/:id/add" => "lists#add_movies", :as => :user_list_list_movie_pairs
post "/users/:username/lists/:id/add" => "lists#submit_movies"
```

These are the classes in my ListsController that should make this possible:

```
def add_movies
  @pair = list.list_movie_pairs.new # "list" is a helper that returns the current list
end

def submit_movies
  @list = current_user.lists.find(params[:id])
  @pair = @list.list_movie_pairs.new(pair_params)
  if @pair.save
    redirect_to user_list_path(current_user.username, @list)
  else
    render :add_movies
  end
end

def list_params
  params.require(:list).permit(:name, :description, :private, \
    list_movie_pairs_attributes: [:id, :list_id, :movie_id, :_destroy], \
    movies_attributes: [:id, :title, :_destroy])
end
```

And this is the form in my view

```
<%= nested_form_for [current_user, list, @pair] do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :movies do |movie_form| %>
    <%= movie_form.text_field :title %>
    <%= movie_form.link_to_remove "Remove movie" %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.link_to_add "Add movie", :movies %>
<% end %>
```

I get this error when trying to access the view:

> Invalid association. Make sure that accepts_nested_attributes_for is used for :movies association.

Which pops at this line:

```
<%= f.link_to_add "Add movie", :movies %>
```

---

Note 1: I am using the Devise gem for users, hence the "current_user" helper;

Note 2: I have tried using both "movies" and "list_movie_pairs", i.e.:

> f.fields for :list_movie_pairs

and

> f.link_to_add "Add movie", :list_movie_pairs

in my view, neither association seems to work

Comment: Try changing your this line `<%= nested_form_for [current_user, list, @pair] do |f| %>` to `<%= nested_form_for [@list, @pair] do |f| %>`

Comment: And in this line `@pair = @list.list_movie_pairs.new(pair_params)` you wrote `pair_params` and actual method name is `list_params`

Comment: @Pavan changing the nested_form_for line won't work, because it would require a different route (i.e list_list_movie_pair_path). Additionally, pair_params is another helper used distinctly for the ListMoviePair objects. Nevertheless, the error could not originate there, as the controller cannot hit the submit_movie method without the user clicking submit - which does not happen because the add_movie view cannot be displayed

Comment: And why are you having a `backslash(\)` in the `list params` method?

Comment: Did you try commenting this line `accepts_nested_attributes_for :movies, :allow_destroy => true` from the `List` model?

Comment: @Pavan I commented it out, still nothing

Answer (score 2):

Your code in the view should be like this

```
<%= nested_form_for [current_user, list, @pair] do |f| %>
<%= f.fields_for :movies do |movie_form| %>
<%= movie_form.text_field :title %>
<%= movie_form.link_to_remove "Remove movie" %>
<%= movie_form.link_to_add "Add movie", :movies %> #note the change here
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

**Update**

There are several issues in your code

1.In your `List` model,this line is not required

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :movies, :allow_destroy => true #not requied
```

2.In your `ListsController`,you have this line

```
@pair = @list.list_movie_pairs.new(pair_params)
```

It should be

`@pair = @list.list_movie_pairs.new(list_params)` because you have `list_params` method not `pair_params`

Comment: I have changed my code accordingly and it still doesn't work, I am getting the same "Invalid association" error

Comment: i will write this here too: I do not believe the pair_params call is causing this, because the controller never gets to call the submit method, since it cannot firstly display the add_movie view (note: calling list_params instead does not work, presumably because the caller is not a List object)

Comment: @razvan9310 Try commenting this line `accepts_nested_attributes_for :movies, :allow_destroy => true` from the List model.